# Google Now reminder sound settings

Tags: audio, google-now

Is there a way to set a Google Now reminder so it makes a sound through phone speakers even when headphones are plugged in? Like alarm does?

The problem for me is that I always have headphones plugged into the phone. And reminder only makes sound in the headphones, so I do not hear it most of the time.

Android Version: 4.4.2
Phone: Nexus 5

Comment: Are you referring to Google+ or Google Now? Your post is tagged google-now but the title/question says Google Plus. Please edit your question to clarify. Thanks.

Comment: @abqnm, I meant Google Now, not Google Plus. Thanks for correction.